# How to compare two arrays to set html multiselect in jsp

Tags: jsp, multi-select, jsp-tags

I maintained a list of selected values from an html multiselect in a string array taken from a database. I want to compare the values of these selected options with the full select option list in order to set them as selected on loading the screen. I keep getting multiple instances for the same select options due to the loop.

```
    <select id="selectForm" name="selectForm" multiple="multiple"> 
        <c:forEach items="${FullList}" var="fullList">
            <c:forEach items="${PreSelected}" var="preSelected">                
                <option ${preSelected== fullList.name ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>${fullList.name}</option>
            </c:forEach> 
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

How do I get a single unique select list with the stored values already selected? Is there a better way of solving the problem than my approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of looping before option element, move loop within option element like given below.

```
<select id="selectForm" name="selectForm" multiple="multiple"> 
  <c:forEach items="${FullList}" var="fullList">
    <option 
     <c:forEach items="${PreSelected}" var="preSelected"> 
      <c:if test="${preSelected== fullList.name}">selected</c:if> 
     </c:forEach>
    >${fullList.name}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```